# Opamp inverter with bias voltage on non-inverting input

Tags: ultrasound, inverting-amplifier

I was reading the datasheet of [TDC1000](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tdc1000.pdf), an ultrasound front-end IC manufactured by Texas Instruments, and had a doubt regarding the biasing scheme (to VCOM) they use for the amplifiers in the Rx path. The power supply for this IC is +5V (VDD) referred to 0V (GND).
[image]
It can be seen that the non-inverting terminal of the LNA is connected to VCOM, which is simply a DC voltage equal to VDD/2. **What is the purpose of biasing it to VCOM?**
[image]
I derived the expression for the output voltage Vo ofthe LNA as

```
Vo=Vcom*(1+Rf/Rin) - Vi*(Rf/Rin)
```

where Vi is input source voltage.

If Vdd=5V and thus Vcom=Vdd/2 = 2.5V, Rf/Rin=9, Vi and Vo varies as shown below:

```
Vi(V) Vo(V)
2.2  5.2
2.3  4.3
2.4  3.4
2.5  2.5
2.6  1.6
2.7  0.7
2.8  -0.2
```

Thus the output varies within the range of its power supply voltage (0 to +5V) when input varies from 2.2 to 2.8V (centered at 2.5V with 0.3V swing on either side). If Vi is outside this small range, Vo will saturate.

Since the input signal to this IC is an ultrasound crystal which generates only a few hundreds of mV (-200 to +200mV), how does this configuration work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, your equation is wrong, because it assumes that Rf and Rin are connected on Vref as well. But the opamp is depicted as example, not a real circuit. It can be a different style/method of op amp that just adds some bias to the amplified signal. The gain is 10, then the amplified signal is added on VCOM potential. At least that's what I think they want to depict in that block diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression for the op-amp based LNA is correct, though I think writing it out in this form is makes it more clear what's going on.

$$ V_o = V_{com} - \left( V_i - V_{com} \right)\left( \dfrac{R_f}{R_{in}} \right) $$

You have a inverting amplifier with a gain of 10x referenced to \$ V_{com} \$.

This is done to allow for operation on a single supply rail, Vo can be above and below Vcom within reason.

The output of the transducer is AC not DC. If it were DC you would need a DC blocking cap on the input.

PS. Your table is slightly off, for Vi = 2.4V, Vo = 3.5V